# How to append something to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

How do I append an object (such as a string or number) to an array in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5342, accepted):

Use the [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to append values to the end of an array:

```js
// initialize array
var arr = [
  "Hi",
  "Hello",
  "Bonjour"
];

// append new value to the array
arr.push("Hola");

console.log(arr);
```

---

You can use the `push()` function to append more than one value to an array in a single call:

```js
// initialize array
var arr = ["Hi", "Hello", "Bonjour", "Hola"];

// append multiple values to the array
arr.push("Salut", "Hey");

// display all values
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Note that the `push()` method returns the updated length of the array.

---

**Update**

If you want to add the items of one array to another array, you can use [`firstArray.concat(secondArray)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
var arr = [
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "cherry"
];

// Do not forget to assign the result as, unlike push, concat does not change the existing array
arr = arr.concat([
  "dragonfruit",
  "elderberry",
  "fig"
]);

console.log(arr);
```

**Update**

Just an addition to this answer if you want to prepend any value to the start of an array (i.e. first index) then you can use [`Array.prototype.unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) for this purpose.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.unshift(0);
console.log(arr);
```

It also supports appending multiple values at once just like `push`.

---

**Update**

Another way with ***ES6*** syntax is to return a new array with the ***[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)***. This leaves the original array unchanged, but returns a new array with new items appended or prepended, compliant with the spirit of functional programming.

```js
const arr = [
  "Hi",
  "Hello",
  "Bonjour",
];

const newArr1 = [
  ...arr,
  "Salut",
];
const newArr2 = [
  "Salut",
  ...arr,
];

console.log(newArr1, newArr2);
```

Comment: Note the return value of .push is not the array (or a new one, like .concat), but an integer representing the array's new length.

Comment: As far as I understand it, [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) (as is `shift`) are the only [in situ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ#Computer_science) variants, while [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) clone the array.

Comment: For sure use the spread option as it doesn't mutate the object.  It should go at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 1119):

If you're only appending a single variable, then `push()` works just fine. If you need to append another array, use `concat()`:

```js
var ar1 = [1, 2, 3];
var ar2 = [4, 5, 6];

var ar3 = ar1.concat(ar2);

alert(ar1);
alert(ar2);
alert(ar3);
```

The concat does not affect `ar1` and `ar2` unless reassigned, for example:

```js
var ar1 = [1, 2, 3];
var ar2 = [4, 5, 6];

ar1 = ar1.concat(ar2);
alert(ar1);
```

There is a lot of great information on *[JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference)*.

Comment: Just making sure people catch the 


var ar3 = ar1.concat(ar2);

part. ar1.concat(ar2) does not save the values into ar1. You have to catch it by assigning it to ar3 or back to ar1, such as:

ar1 = ar1.concat(ar2);

Comment: I'd say this is the wrong answer actually. The question was `How do I append to an array in JavaScript?`, but `concat` actually **creates** a **new** array. That is an important difference! Instead I'd say the answer below by Omnimike is actually the best one: Use **Push.apply** to push a whole array to an existing array without creating a new one.

Comment: @StijndeWitt you can still append without creating a new array, as stated in the previous comment `ar1 = ar1.concat(ar2);` will append to `ar1`

Comment: @cameronjonesweb Actually, what it does is create a new array with the same contents as `ar1`, append `ar2` and then return the new array. Just leave out the assignment part (`ar1 = ...`) from that line of code and you'll see that the *original* `ar1` did not in fact change. If you want to avoid making a copy, you'll need `push`. Don't believe me, believe [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat): "The concat() method returns a new array"  First sentence in the docs for `concat`.

Comment: @StijndeWitt You're right. But, a different way to look at it though, .push only works well in adding single variables/objects, but will however mess up when it comes to appending Arrays, which `ar2` above is anyways. The result of `.push` in the scenario will be `= [ar1, [ar2]]`. .concat solves that problem, but with sacrifice of speed and a new array created. To use `.push` properly in array appends, loop out the contained element first and push each. `ar2.forEach(each => {
      ar1.push(each);
      });`

Comment: To append a complete array with `push`, use [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which allows us to specify the parameters to a function as a single array. This works because `push` accepts a variable number of arguments and will push all arguments passed. Array is actually a very clever object with just a couple of methods that are very versatile. Try it: `var array = ['look', 'an', 'array'];
var result = [];
result.push.apply(result, array);
console.info(result);`

Comment: `ar1.push(...ar2)` will append all of the items in the second array to the first without creating a new array or invoking a `for` loop of any kind.

Comment: @StijndeWitt OP never mentioned he wanted it mutable and/or in a single call without reassignments, he even wasn't referring to an array, he wanted `push`. Appending an array to an array is a plus here, so yes, it's perfectly acceptable to use `concat`.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo He said *append* and append implies the existing array changes. Also for performance one should usually use `[].push.apply(arrayToAppendTo, arrayToAppend)`. But hey, choose whichever suits your needs best. As long as you understand there is a big difference.

Answer (score 428):

Some quick benchmarking (each test = 500k appended elements and the results are averages of multiple runs) showed the following:

Firefox 3.6 (Mac):

- Small arrays: **`arr[arr.length] = b` is faster** (300ms vs. 800ms)
- Large arrays: **`arr.push(b)` is faster** (500ms vs. 900ms)

Safari 5.0 (Mac):

- Small arrays: **`arr[arr.length] = b` is faster** (90ms vs. 115ms)
- Large arrays: **`arr[arr.length] = b` is faster** (160ms vs. 185ms)

Google Chrome 6.0 (Mac):

- Small arrays: **No significant difference** (and Chrome is FAST! Only ~38ms !!)
- Large arrays: **No significant difference** (160ms)

I like the `arr.push()` syntax better, but I think I'd be better off with the `arr[arr.length]` Version, at least in raw speed. I'd love to see the results of an IE run though.

---

My benchmarking loops:

```
function arrpush_small() {
    var arr1 = [];
    for (a = 0; a < 100; a++)
    {
        arr1 = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            arr1.push('elem' + i);
        }
    }
}

function arrlen_small() {
    var arr2 = [];
    for (b = 0; b < 100; b++)
    {
        arr2 = [];
        for (j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
        {
            arr2[arr2.length] = 'elem' + j;
        }
    }
}


function arrpush_large() {
    var arr1 = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        arr1.push('elem' + i);
    }
}

function arrlen_large() {
    var arr2 = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 500000; j++)
    {
        arr2[arr2.length] = 'elem' + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is if .length is a stored value or is calculated when being accessed, since if the latter one is true then it might be that using a simple variable (such as j) as the index value might be even faster

Comment: Would love to see concat() in the same test!

Comment: I wonder how much this has changed in the past four years. (jsperf would be handy right now.)

Comment: This type of benchmarking is interesting, but ironically not very helpful in making apps faster. The rendering loop is by far much much more expensive during any cycle. In addition these internals of the JS language are continuously being optimized by browser developers.  Thats the reason for my downvote, not the interestingness of this answer. If you want faster apps, benchmark first and see what to change - 99 out of 100 times it won't be an issue like this test shows. Often its poor developer JS/CSS - not browser internals that is making it slow.

Comment: For the ease of others, I created a jsperf with @JensRoland's tests: http://jsperf.com/pushetc go ahead and add your own comparations and update it.

Comment: I agree with LessQuesar in sticking to the builtins whenever possible. Not that micro-optimization is bad in itself, but he's right that browsers are always improving their engine speed. Case in point: as of this writing, the per-browser performance is nearly identical for all the techniques listed above. Meaning a lot of fuss a few years ago for such a small gain, when now there is no gain.

Comment: Oh, and Chrome is only fast because it forces its priority, in cases speeding up the interrupt cycle to ensure its speed, and opening lots and lots of processes.

Answer (score 341):

I think it's worth mentioning that push can be called with multiple arguments, which will be appended to the array in order. For example:

```js
var arr = ['first'];
arr.push('second', 'third');
console.log(arr);
```

As a result of this you can use push.apply to append an array to another array like so:

```js
var arr = ['first'];
arr.push('second', 'third');
arr.push.apply(arr, ['forth', 'fifth']);
console.log(arr);
```

[Annotated ES5](https://es5.github.io/) has more info on exactly what [push](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.7) and [apply](https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3) do.

2016 update: with [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you don't need that `apply` anymore, like:

```js
var arr = ['first'];
arr.push('second', 'third');

arr.push(...['fourth', 'fifth']);
console.log(arr) ;
```

Comment: best answer for appending an array of items while not creating a new array.

Comment: @GabrielLittman Specially because appending to an array, IMHO, should modify the array, not create a new one.

Comment: I like the push.apply version, would rather use `Array.prototype.push.apply()` though.

Comment: Sometimes it's important to preserve the reference to an array - for example in AngularJs when an array is in scope on some controller and some service needs to update the data in the array for display. That's why I'm upvoting this solution.

Answer (score 86):

You can use the `push` and `apply` functions to append two arrays.

```js
var array1 = [11, 32, 75];
var array2 = [99, 67, 34];

Array.prototype.push.apply(array1, array2);
console.log(array1);
```

It will append `array2` to `array1`. Now `array1` contains `[11, 32, 75, 99, 67, 34]`.
This code is much simpler than writing `for` loops to copy each and every items in the array.

Comment: This is what i required, maintain original array reference

Comment: If you are using ES6/7 you can also the `...` operator instead of apply
    ```const a1 = []
    const a2 = [5,6,7]
    const.push(...a2)```

edit: syntax highlight

Comment: I'd use `array1.concat(array2)` in this situation. The call to `push` seems unnecessary.

Comment: `concat` makes a copy. The call to `push` is no more unnecessary than the call to `concat`. For appending multiple items to an existing array, `push` is the best solution.

Answer (score 73):

With the new ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), joining two arrays using `push` becomes even easier:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
arr.push(...arr2);
console.log(arr);
```

This adds the contents of `arr2` onto the end of `arr`.

[Babel REPL Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20arr%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D%3B%0Aarr.push(...%5B6%2C%207%2C%208%2C%209%2C%2010%5D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(arr)%3B)

Answer (score 57):

If `arr` is an array, and `val` is the value you wish to add use:

```
arr.push(val);
```

E.g.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr.push('d');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 53):

Use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [3, 4, 5];
a = a.concat(b);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 49):

JavaScript with the [ECMAScript 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition) (ES5) standard which is supported by most browsers now, you can use `apply()` to append `array1` to `array2`.

```
var array1 = [3, 4, 5];
var array2 = [1, 2];

Array.prototype.push.apply(array2, array1);

console.log(array2); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

JavaScript with [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) (ES6) standard which is supported by [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox), [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer), and [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), you can use the `spread` operator:

```
"use strict";
let array1 = [3, 4, 5];
let array2 = [1, 2];

array2.push(...array1);

console.log(array2); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The `spread` operator will replace `array2.push(...array1);` with `array2.push(3, 4, 5);` when the browser is thinking the logic.

**Bonus point**

If you'd like to create *another* variable to store all the items from both arrays, you can do this:

**ES5** `var combinedArray = array1.concat(array2);`

**ES6** `const combinedArray = [...array1, ...array2]`

The spread operator (`...`) is to spread out all items from a collection.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to append two arrays -

```
var a = ['a', 'b'];
var b = ['c', 'd'];
```

then you could use:

```
var c = a.concat(b);
```

And if you want to add record `g` to array  (`var a=[]`) then you could use:

```
a.push('g');
```

Answer (score 32):

**There are a couple of ways to append an array in JavaScript:**

**1)** The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.push(4, 5);
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**2)** The `unshift()` method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.unshift(4, 5);
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

**3)** The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method **does not change** the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

```
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var arr2 = ["d", "e", "f"];
var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

Output:

```
[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
```

**4)** You can use the array's `.length` property to add an element to the end of the array:

```
var ar = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
ar[ar.length] = 'four';
console.log( ar );
```

Output:

```
 ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

**5)** The `splice()` method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements:

```
var myFish = ["angel", "clown", "mandarin", "surgeon"];
myFish.splice(4, 0, "nemo");
//array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
console.log(myFish);
```

Output:

```
["angel", "clown", "mandarin", "surgeon","nemo"]
```

**6)** You can also add a new element to an array simply by specifying a new index and assigning a value:

```
var ar = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
ar[3] = 'four'; // add new element to ar
console.log(ar);
```

Output:

```
["one", "two","three","four"]
```

Comment: For 1), this says "without modifying the original array." But that's literally what `push` does: it modifies the original array by pushing new elements onto it. Am I reading this wrong, or should this be edited?

Answer (score 25):

The `push()` method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length. Example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");

// The result of fruits will be:
Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango, Kiwi
```

The exact answer to your question is already answered, but let's look at some other ways to add items to an array.

The `unshift()` method adds new items to the beginning of an array, and returns the new length. Example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.unshift("Lemon", "Pineapple");

// The result of fruits will be:
Lemon, Pineapple, Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango
```

And lastly, the `concat()` method is used to join two or more arrays. Example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange"];
var moreFruits = ["Apple", "Mango", "Lemon"];
var allFruits = fruits.concat(moreFruits);

// The values of the children array will be:
Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango, Lemon
```

Answer (score 25):

Now, you can take advantage of [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) syntax and just do

```
let array = [1, 2];
console.log([...array, 3]);
```

keeping the original array immutable.

Answer (score 21):

**Append a single element**

```
// Append to the end
arrName.push('newName1');

// Prepend to the start
arrName.unshift('newName1');

// Insert at index 1
arrName.splice(1, 0,'newName1');
// 1: index number, 0: number of element to remove, newName1: new element


// Replace index 3 (of exists), add new element otherwise.
arrName[3] = 'newName1';
```

**Append multiple elements**

```
// Insert from index number 1
arrName.splice(1, 0,'newElemenet1', 'newElemenet2', 'newElemenet3');
// 1: index number from where insert starts,
// 0: number of element to remove,
//newElemenet1,2,3: new elements
```

**Append an array**

```
// Join two or more arrays
arrName.concat(newAry1, newAry2);
//newAry1,newAry2: Two different arrays which are to be combined (concatenated) to an existing array
```

Comment: Why not `arrName.push('newElemenet1, newElemenet2, newElemenet3')`?

Comment: In the push() it insert the element in last but in my example it insert the element at middle i.e. from the array index 1(as per the example)@Mihail Malostanidis

Comment: Oh, I thought the assumption was that `arrName` was of length `1`.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) you can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to do it.

```
var arr = [
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "cherry"
];

var arr2 = [
    "dragonfruit",
    "elderberry",
    "fig"
];

arr.push(...arr2);
```

Answer (score 17):

If you know the highest index (such as stored in a variable "i") then you can do

```
myArray[i + 1] = someValue;
```

However, if you don't know then you can either use

```
myArray.push(someValue);
```

as other answers suggested, or you can use

```
myArray[myArray.length] = someValue;
```

Note that the array is zero based so *.length* returns the highest index plus one.

Also note that you don't have to add in order and you can actually skip values, as in

```
myArray[myArray.length + 1000] = someValue;
```

In which case the values in between will have a value of *undefined*.

It is therefore a good practice when looping through a JavaScript to verify that a value actually exists at that point.

This can be done by something like the following:

```
if(myArray[i] === "undefined"){ continue; }
```

If you are certain that you don't have any zeros in the array then you can just do:

```
if(!myArray[i]){ continue; }
```

Of course, make sure in this case that you don't use as the condition myArray[i] (as some people over the Internet suggest based on the end that as soon as `i` is greater than the highest index, it will return *undefined* which evaluates to *false*).

Comment: You actually do not mean `"undefined"`.  It must read `void 0`!  `"undefined"` is a string and `"undefined" !== void 0`, hence your `if(myArray[i]` is false unless the array at index `i` is set to the string with the contents equivalent of `'u'+'n'+'d'+'e'+'f'+'i'+'n'+'e'+'d'`.  Also note that you should not use `undefined`, instead use `void 0`.  Because `void 0` always is the undefined value, while `undefined` can be defined via something like `function x(undefined) { alert(undefined) } x("hello world")`, so you cannot be sure if somebody accidentally set `window["undefined"]=1` or similar.

Answer (score 16):

**You can do it using JavaScript [Spread Operator Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):**

```
// Initialize the array

var arr = [
    "Hi",
    "Hello",
    "Bangladesh"
];

// Append a new value to the array

arr = [...arr, "Feni"]; 

// Or you can add a variable value

var testValue = "Cool";

arr = [...arr, testValue ];

console.log(arr);

// Final output [ 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Bangladesh', 'Feni', 'Cool' ]
```

Comment: This doesn't append the value to the array, which is what the OP asked. This creates a new array, with the contents of the old array and the new elements. Really, this is Array.concat.

Comment: Which feature of ES6 in particular? What is the (official) name of the feature?

Answer (score 12):

`concat()`, of course, can be used with two-dimensional arrays as well. No looping required.

```
var a = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4] ];

var b = [
    ["a", "b"],
    ["c", "d"] ];

b = b.concat(a);

alert(b[2][1]); // Result: 2
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Let the array length property do the work:

```
myarray[myarray.length] = 'new element value added to the end of the array';
```

myarray.length returns the number of strings in the array.
**JavaScript is zero-based**, so the next element key of the array will be the current length of the array.

Example:

```
var myarray = [0, 1, 2, 3],
    myarrayLength = myarray.length; // myarrayLength is set to 4
```

Answer (score 11):

> Just want to add a snippet for non-destructive addition of an element.

```
var newArr = oldArr.concat([newEl]);
```

Answer (score 9):

### Append a value to an array

Since [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds one or more elements to the end of an array and *returns the new length of the array*, sometimes we want just to get the new up-to-date array so we can do something like so:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const val = 4;

arr.concat([val]); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or just:

```
[...arr, val] // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Correct with ES6 for rest operator.

Answer (score 6):

### Append a single item

To append a single item to an array, use the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method provided by the Array object:

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'pear', 'apple']
fruits.push('mango')
console.log(fruits)
```

`push()` mutates the original array.

To create a new array instead, use the [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) Array method:

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'pear', 'apple']
const allfruits = fruits.concat('mango')
console.log(allfruits)
```

Notice that `concat()` does not actually add an item to the array, but creates a new array, which you can assign to another variable, or reassign to the original array (declaring it as `let`, as you cannot reassign a `const`):

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'pear', 'apple']
const allfruits = fruits.concat('mango')
console.log(allfruits)
```

```js
let fruits = ['banana', 'pear', 'apple']
fruits = fruits.concat('mango')
```

### Append multiple items

To append a multiple item to an array, you can use [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) by calling it with multiple arguments:

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'pear', 'apple']
fruits.push('mango', 'melon', 'avocado')
console.log(fruits)
```

You can also use the [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method you saw before, passing a list of items separated by a comma:

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'pear', 'apple']
const allfruits = fruits.concat('mango', 'melon', 'avocado')
console.log(allfruits)
```

or an array:

```
const fruits = ['banana', 'pear', 'apple']
const allfruits = fruits.concat(['mango', 'melon', 'avocado'])
console.log(allfruits)
```

Remember that as described previously this method does not mutate the original array, but it  returns a new array.

> Originally [posted at](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-append-item-to-array/)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to combine two arrays without the duplicate you may try the code below:

```
array_merge = function (arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.concat(arr2.filter(function(item){
    return arr1.indexOf(item) < 0;
  }))
}
```

**Usage:**

```
array1 = ['1', '2', '3']
array2 = ['2', '3', '4', '5']
combined_array = array_merge(array1, array2)
```

**Output:**

[1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to append a single value into an array, simply use the push method. It will add a new element at the end of the array.

But if you intend to add multiple elements then store the elements in a new array and concat the second array with the first array...either way you wish.

```
arr=['a','b','c'];
arr.push('d');
//now print the array in console.log and it will contain 'a','b','c','d' as elements.
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 4):

You .push() that value in. 
**Example:** array.push(value);

Answer (score 3):

We don't have an *append* function for Array in JavaScript, but we have **push** and **unshift**. Imagine you have the array below:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

And we like to append a value to this array. We can do *arr.push(6)*, and it will add 6 to the end of the array:

```
arr.push(6); // Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Also we can use *unshift*, look at how we can apply this:

```
arr.unshift(0); // Returns [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

They are main functions to add or append new values to the arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the push() if you want to add values,
e.g. `arr.push("Test1", "Test2");`.

If you have array you can use concat(), e.g. `Array1.concat(Array2)`.

If you have just one element to add, you can also try the *length* method, e.g. `array[aray.length] = 'test';`.

Answer (score 2):

Appending items on an array

```
let fruits = ["orange", "banana", "apple", "lemon"]; /* Array declaration */

fruits.push("avacado"); /* Adding an element to the array */

/* Displaying elements of the array */

for(var i=0; i < fruits.length; i++){
  console.log(fruits[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *push* method.

```
Array.prototype.append = function(destArray){
    destArray = destArray || [];
    this.push.call(this, ...destArray);
    return this;
}
var arr = [1,2,5,67];
var arr1 = [7,4,7,8];
console.log(arr.append(arr1)); // [7, 4, 7, 8, 1, 4, 5, 67, 7]
console.log(arr.append("Hola")) // [1, 2, 5, 67, 7, 4, 7, 8, "H", "o", "l", "a"]
```

Comment: Can you add a reference to the push method? Is it *[Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)*?

Answer (score 1):

`push()` adds a new element to the end of an array.

`pop()` removes an element from the end of an array.

To append an object (such as a string or number) to an array, use:

```
array.push(toAppend);
```