# Find duplicates in an array and remove them out using javascript

Tags: javascript

how to find duplicates in an array and remove them using javascript?

Comment: What type variables will be in the array? Only strings?

Comment: sorry wasnt specific,i was thinking both string and integer arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unique() for arrays in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890203/unique-for-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this generically, you could use something like the following, which removes duplicates from the array in place. If you have an array that contains only strings or numbers, you could simplify this significantly.

```
var arrayContains = Array.prototype.indexOf ?
    function(arr, val) {
        return arr.indexOf(val) > -1;
    } :

    function(arr, val) {
        var i = arr.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (arr[i] === val) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

function removeDuplicates(arr, equals) {
    var val, originalArr = arr.slice(0);
    arr.length = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = originalArr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        val = originalArr[i];
        if (!arrayContains(arr, val)) {
            arr.push(val);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3];
removeDuplicates(arr);
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sampleArr=new Array(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4); //Declare array
document.write(uniqueArr(sampleArr)); //Print the unique value

//Adds new uniqueArr values to temp array
function uniqueArr(a) {
 temp = new Array();
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  if(!contains(temp, a[i])){
   temp.length+=1;
   temp[temp.length-1]=a[i];
  }
 }
 return temp;
}

//Will check for the Uniqueness
function contains(a, e) {
 for(j=0;j<a.length;j++)if(a[j]==e)return true;
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] == arr[i])
        {
            arr.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}
```