# handling js arrays with jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am wanting to store some info in array

i declared an array

```
var added = [];
```

**Question**: I want to add a number/string at the last of the array.

And then i want to add all the data to the a dom ?
I am new to js array please help me out with this basic things

Comment: Here is similar question that can help  
refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/newbie-javascript-appending-to-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
added.push("123");
added.push("abc");
$('div').html(added.join());
```

This will set the html of the div to `123,abc`

Comment: I want to do something like this $("div").html(added)

Answer (score -1):

```
added.push("123");
added.push("abc");
added.push("xyz");

for(i in added)
{
 $("div").append(added[i]);  


}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

I though you need to assign all one by one!

You could use:

```
$("div").html(added.join(', '));
```

to get things seperated by comma!

Comment: Yea i found out the .push but wasnt able to check what does the array contains so :D thanks :D

Comment: @Evan Trimboli : could you explain why is it a poor practise?