# How make array Json javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

***Hi, I have a problem with the next code:***

### javascript

```js
var cadena="[";


    $('.box').each(function(){

            var clase=$(this).attr("class");          
            var id_t=$(this).attr("id");

            if(clase=="box todo"){
               var status_t="todo";
                //alert('hola');
            }
            if(clase=="box inprocess"){
                var status_t="inprocess";
                //alert('hola');
            }
            if(clase=="box testing"){
                var status_t="testing";
                //alert('hola');
            }
            if(clase=="box done"){
                var status_t="done";
                //alert('hola');
            }

            //alert('tarea es: '+id_t+ ' con clase '+status_t);

            var objeto={};
            objeto["id"]=id_t;
            objeto["status"]=status_t;


            var json = JSON.stringify(objeto);

            //alert(json);
            cadena=cadena+json;

    });



    cadena= cadena+"]";
 alert('cadena Json '+cadena);
```

---

I get this chain Json, but this chain is wrong because it need be separate with (,)
   I haven't idea that do

```html
[
{"id":"1","status":"1"}
{"id":"2","status":"2"}
{"id":"3","status":"1"}
]
```

and I need a chain Json valid, I want something similar to this

```html
[
{"id":"1","status":"1"},
{"id":"2","status":"2"},
{"id":"3","status":"1"}
]
```

any ideas to take me to this result
   I will be very grateful.
   THANKS!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Instead of the below line,

```
var cadena = "["
```

try

```
 //to init array 
  var cadena = [];
```

And, instead of this line,

```
cadena = cadena+json;
```

Try this

```
cadena.push(json);
```

And **remove** this line :

```
cadena= cadena + "]";
```

For more info, see this question : [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array).

And you could simplify your code to this :

```
 $('.box').each(function () {

     //taking out the second element of the class and assigning it directly to status_t variable
     var status_t = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
     var id_t = $(this).attr("id");

     var objeto = { "id" : id_t, "status" : status_t};

     cadena.push(json);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do it like this:

```
var cadena = $('.box').map( function( e ) {
    var $e = $(e);
    return {
        id: $e.attr('id'),
        status: $e.attr('class').replace( /^box /, '' )
    }
});

var json = JSON.stringify( cadena );
console.log( json );
```

I don't have a way to test that, but unless I missed something it should work. If you post some sample HTML I could make sure it's correct.