# Print out an array in C without [] and () operators - how to?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote such code, but it shows only this:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

...

and thats not the output I would like to get.

Heres the code:

```
void fun(int *tab, int n)
{
    int i, wsk = &tab;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *(tab+1));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int tab[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    fun(tab, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

The second version I tried, doesnt work at all:

```
void fun(int *tab, int n)
{
    int i, wsk = &tab;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *(wsk+i));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int tab[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    fun(tab, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Code::Blocks says that:

```
|49|error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)|
```

Comment: in first code change `*(tab+1)` to `*(tab+i)`. and remove wsk.

Comment: Without "*`()` operator*" would mean what, please?

Comment: Without `()`: `int * tabi = tab + i; printf("%d\n", *tabi);` (Not using parentheses as expression-grouping-operators, not using them at all would (probably) be impossible)

Comment: @alk ehm `*(tab+1)` are you about this? without `()` will changed operations priority so it'll executed as `*(tab)+1` it means: **1.** unname `tab` pointer with 0 shift - we get 0's element = 1; **2.** add 1 = 2;

Comment: @Kninnug: Ah, so all answers so far are wrong?

Comment: @alk, why do you dicided so? To all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array js beginner question upvoted. C beginner question downvoted.

Comment: @alk I don't know that, but they do use parentheses where it's possible without. I upvoted your answer as it addresses both constraints as much as possible.

Comment: @vlastachu It wasn't me <tm>, at least not for the question!

Comment: is it correct to say `() operator` when in c++ exist termin `() operator` which means `someObj(otherObj)`? Also if taken the question literally in that case it is impossible (write `printf` without parenthness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No grouping parentheses, nor subscript. No clutter:

```
void fun(int *tab, int n)
{
    while (n--)
        printf("%d\n", *tab++);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
printf("%d\n", *(tab+1));
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", *(tab+i));
```

And in both programs:

```
int i, wsk = &tab;
```

should be:

```
int i, *wsk = tab;
```

**EDIT:** OP actually also has this constraint in the title  `without [] and () operators`. 
Although one usually refers to the `()` operator for the cast operator, the `()` of the function call is also called the *function-call operator* in the C Standard and is listed with postfix operators in the Standard. Therefore I think this OP constraint is put the wrong way because without function call I doubt there is any valid answer to OP question.

Comment: Without "*() operator*"?

Comment: @alk there is no `()` operator in C other than the cast operator which is not used in this answer. If the no `()` operator actually meant without `()` then `printf` cannot be used and if no function call can be used, I doubt there is any solution to the question.

Comment: I fully agree about the "*() operator*" and was just try to provoke a comment ... sorry and thanks. @ouah

Comment: @alk I think the OP constraint has been put the wrong way, I added an edit in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> ...  without [] and () operators

It should be something like this then:

```
void fun(const int * tab, const size_t n)
{
  const int * wsk = tab;
  size_t i = 0;
  for(; i < n; ++i, ++wsk)
  {
      printf("%d\n", *wsk);
  }
}
```

Comment: `for(int* i = tab; i != tab + n; i++) printf("%d\n", *i);`

Comment: @vlastachu: More operations then mine. This one is the nicest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20459714/694576

Answer (score 1):

You want to print what tab is pointing to so do not use &tab

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(tab+i));
}
```

in your first version you are always printing the second element, the *(tab+1) is basically
"what tab is pointing to +1" which is the second element
what you want is what tab is pointing to + a counter that increases by 1 each iteration, which is your i :)

edit:
Sorry didnt notice that you didnt want () either.
*tab++

Comment: Without "*() operator*"?