# Getting undefined in dropdown from json content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**EDIT 2**

Check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SN5zT/2/

Following is the fiddle for which I am not sure why I am getting undefined in dropdown.

My fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/z6GDj/

```
var res = '{"allSportPosition":{"25":"Forwards (Strickers)","27":"Fullbacks (Defenders)","28":"Goalkeeper ","26":"Midfielders"}}';


try {
    var sportPositionOptions = '';
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(res);
    var allSportPosition = parsedJson.allSportPosition;
    var values = new Array();
    $.each(allSportPosition, function (index, value) {
        values[index] = value;
    });
    //alert(values.length);
    values.sort();
    $.each(values, function (atIndex, atValue) {
        sportPositionOptions = sportPositionOptions + '<option value="' + atIndex + '">' + atValue + '</option>';
    });
    $(sportPositionOptions).appendTo("#player");

} catch (e) {
    alert("Parsing error:" + e);
}
```

`$.each` is automatically sorting keys to 25,26,27,28 for `res`.

Please explain the reason of this and why I  am getting undefined ?

Let me know If i need to explain it more, I will surely do it :)

**EDIT**

Please explain the reason why it is getting sorted automatically http://jsfiddle.net/SN5zT/

Comment: There is no notion of order in objects, they are sorted however the browser chooses to sort them.

Comment: @adeneo Please explain this behavior http://jsfiddle.net/SN5zT/  as u can see it is getting sorted

Comment: @Trialcoder: Check my answer. However, still trying find why your code wasn't working.

Comment: What you have is an object of objects, and there is no order in objects, if the browser chooses to order the object in a certain way when parsed, that's fine, but it's up to the browser, there is no standard that sets a specification for a certain sorting order on objects, they are by default unsorted as they are made up of named keys and values.

Comment: You're expecting the object to be outputted in a certain order, and I'm not sure how to better explain this, but there is no order in objects. You can't expect the object to be iterated over in any given order, as there is no order.

Comment: And as a sidenote, it's not jQuery or `$.each` that messes up the order of your object (that doesn't have order), it's `JSON.parse`, so the only option is to wrap the objects in an array, which has order, and not an object.

Comment: @adeneo I just edited the fiddle so that I think we are on the same note http://jsfiddle.net/SN5zT/1/

Comment: We are on the same page, and the fiddle makes it even more clear. You're expecting to get the order in the dropdown that you have in the JSON string, but the JSON string is parsed into an object with objects, and ***there is no order in objects*** so you can't expect any order at all.

Comment: And this is how it should be done -> http://jsfiddle.net/SN5zT/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
values.push(value);
```

instead of

```
values[index] = value;
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/z6GDj/1)**

Comment: he loses his indexes, which might be important ?

Comment: I need to keep the indexes please check this fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/SN5zT/

Comment: @budhram I am accepting yours as I managed to work without the indexes :)

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` is doing the following assignment that is why you are getting so many undefined

```
values[25] = "Forwards (Strickers)"
values[26] = "Midfielders"
values[27] = "Fullbacks (Defenders)"
values[28] = "Goalkeeper"
```

During `$.each` browsers will automatically sort the keys if the keys are integer, one way to avoid this is use non integer keys

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing an object to each(), jquery passes the key as the index parameter. In your object, the keys are ranged from 25 to 28. Setting the array using the values[25] on an empty array will expand the array to index 25, with the first 25 elements undefined. Using values.push(value) will append the value at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The following script is working, I also figured out where the "undefineds" came from.

http://jsfiddle.net/z6GDj/3/

```
var res = '{"allSportPosition":{"25":"Forwards (Strickers)","27":"Fullbacks (Defenders)","28":"Goalkeeper ","26":"Midfielders"}}';


try{
var sportPositionOptions = '';    
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(res);
var allSportPosition = parsedJson.allSportPosition;
var values = allSportPosition;
//$.each(allSportPosition, function(index, value) {
//    values[index] = value;
//});
//alert(values.length);

$.each(values,function(atIndex, atValue){       
    sportPositionOptions = sportPositionOptions+'<option value="'+atIndex+'">'+atValue+'</option>';            
});
$(sportPositionOptions).appendTo("#player");

}
catch(e){
    alert("Parsing error:"+ e); 
    }
```

> The array is sorted automatically, because the keys are set correctly.
>   see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp.  "An array can hold
>   many values under a single name, and you can access the values by
>   referring to an index number."

Or: Change the index, and you´re  changing the order. (index indicates the order).

The undefined values are created by javascript default, check the last answer in here ([How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array))

> "Also note that you don't have to add in order and you can actually
>   skip values, as in
>
> myArray[myArray.length + 1000] = someValue;
>
> In which case the values in between will have a value of undefined."

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is define your options before you sort them , and then append them to your select:

```
var res = '{"allSportPosition":{"25":"Forwards (Strickers)","27":"Fullbacks (Defenders)","28":"Goalkeeper ","26":"Midfielders"}}';


try {
    var sportPositionOptions = '',
        parsedJson = JSON.parse(res),
        allSportPosition = parsedJson.allSportPosition,
        options = new Array();

    $.each(allSportPosition, function (index, value) {
        options[index] = $('<option></option>', {
            value: index,
            text: value
        });
    });

    $.each(options, function (index) {
        $('#player').append(options[index]);
    });

} catch (e) {
    alert("Parsing error:" + e);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6GDj/11/

Comment: Still losing index value. :) I checked it. Here http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/z6GDj/8

Comment: You need to create your options in the array before you sort them, and then just append them to your select. Check my answer for example.