# How to store an array with Mongoose + Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new on MongoDB and I wanted to store an array.

Here's an example of what I want

```
question : {
    question : "My question",
    answer   : "My answer",
    subQuestions : 
    [0] {
        question: "My sub question",
        answer  : "My sub answer"
    },
    [1] {
        question: "My other sub question", 
        answer  : "My other sub answer"
    }
}
```

But I didn't succeed to put multiple entries in subQuestions. I got this instead :

```
question : {
    question : "My question",
    answer   : "My answer",
    subQuestions : {
        question {
            [0] : "My sub question",
            [1] : "My other sub question"
        },
        answer {
            [0] : "My sub answer",
            [1] : "My other sub answer"
        }
    }
}
```

What I have actually is hard to process in front and I really wanted to have what I've showed in the first bloc.

This is my actual Schema :

```
var Questions = new Schema({
    question: { type: String },
    answer  : { type: String },
    subQuestions : {
        question : [String],
        answer   : [String]
    }
});
```

And my saving script :

```
var q = new Questions;
q.subQuestions.question = ["My sub question", "My other sub question"];
q.subQuestions.answer   = ["My sub answer", "My other sub answer"];

q.save(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Can someone help me with this ? I'm on it from awhile so maybe it's just a little thing that I didn't think about.

Thank you very much in advance and don't hesitate to ask me questions.

Comment: How does your mongoose schema look like?

Comment: Thanks for helping. My actual mongoose Schema look like the third block code on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to define an array in your schema:

```
var Questions = new Schema({
    question: { type: String },
    answer  : { type: String },
    subQuestions : [{
        question : String,
        answer   : String
    }]
});
```

Note that I changed your curly braces.

To add a new subquestion you can use [push()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array):

```
q = new Questions
sq.question = "How are you doing?"
sq.answer = "Great."
q.subQuestions.push(sq)
```

I didn't test this code but it first assembles a JavaScript object from two strings (this is the `sq` object) and then pushes it to the array.