# How to push an object into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array containing objects and I want to add a new object to it.

```
//here is my array    
var countries = [
    { start: 20.2, end: 20.7, country_name: "United States" },
    { start: 20.7, end: 21.2, country_name: "Canada" }
]

//new object to push in this array    
{ start: 23.2, end: 23.7, country_name: "Peru" }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try search for your problem first. It is fairly common and can be found pretty easily. The solution would be to use `push()` of `Array`, well you got your answers now.

Answer (score 4):

Did you read documentation? I hope you'll try to search first at the next time. Let's make SO free from SUCH trivial questions

```
countries.push({ start: 23.2, end: 23.7, country_name: "Peru" })
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
var newObj = { start: 23.2, end: 23.7, country_name: "Peru" }
countries.push(newObj);
```