# Javascript/AngularJs - How do I fill an array with objects from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Something I'm trying to do in an angularjs app that I'm making. I have a large array of the cast of a movie including directors, producers, film crew etc. and I want to make a new array of just the director(s).

I don't know how to fill a new array with specific objects form another array.
Here's a quick simple example of what I mean:

```
this.products = [
  {name: "apple", category: "fruit"}, 
  {name: "iPhone", category: "tech"}, 
  {name: "banana", category: "fruit"}
];

this.fruits = [];

for(i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  if (products.category[i] == "fruit") {
    /*code to add object to fruits array*/
 }
}
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Numerous javascript array methods you can use depending on expected results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `filter` API:

```
this.fruits = this.products.filter(function(product) {
                  return product.category == 'fruits';
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (products[i].category == "fruit") {
        fruits.push(products[i].name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code this may do helpful for you

```
this.products = [
    {name: "apple", category: "fruit"}, 
    {name: "iPhone", category: "tech"}, 
    {name: "banana", category: "fruit"}
];

this.fruits = [];

for(i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (products[i].category === "fruit") {
        /*code to add object to fruits array*/

        fruits.push(products[i].name);
    }
}

console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
this.fruits = this.products.filter(p => p.category == "fruit").map(p => p.name);
```

The `.filter()` method takes only the objects with the right category. Then `.map()` goes through this result, and replaces the objects by the name property value only, so that the final result is `["apple", "banana"]`.

If you want the objects as a whole, then of course you leave out the `.map()` part.

Demo:

```js
new (function () {
    this.products = [
      {name: "apple", category: "fruit"}, 
      {name: "iPhone", category: "tech"}, 
      {name: "banana", category: "fruit"}
    ];

    this.fruits = this.products.filter(p => p.category == "fruit").map(p => p.name);

    document.write(this.fruits);
});
```