# How to append new ListElement in QML?

Tags: json, qt, qml, qt5.6

So, I need a button that would add a new ListElement to existing list. I need to fill in one value, taken from TextField. I have no idea how to do this. I tried something like

```
onClicked:{
nameOfList.append(JSON.parse([nameOfList.nameOfColumn,myTextField.text]));
}
```

Obviously it didn't work. Do I have to send these two values to C++, then make a QJsonObject and send it back, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the question does not describe the type of `nameOfList`, I assume it is `ListModel` since the question is about adding a new `ListElement`. In that case, appending would be straightforward:

```
onClicked:{
 nameOfList.append({"nameOfColumn": myTextField.text})}
}
```

However, if `nameOfList.nameOfColumn` is not constant, you'd need to make a temporary:

```
var temp = {}
temp[nameOfList.nameOfColumn] = myTextField.text
nameOfList.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on what exactly `nameOfList` is, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array) you will most probably find an answer.