# Javascript Array add or update

Tags: javascript, arrays

Javascript Array push issue

I have a object:

```
people: [{name: peter, age: 27, email:'peter@abc.com'}]
```

I want to push:

```
people.push({
        name: 'John',
        age: 13,
        email: 'john@abc.com'
});
people.push({
        name: 'peter',
        age: 36,
        email: 'peter@abc.com'
});
```

The finally I want is:

```
people: [
{name: 'peter', age: 36, email:'peter@abc.com'},
{name: 'john', age: 13, email:'john@abc.com'},
]
```

I dont have any key but the email is a unique

Comment: What's the issue? Duplicate entries?

Comment: Everything looks correct, except for trailing comma in the resulting array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you saying that you want to push only unique e-mails?

Comment: So what's the problem? As you have it, and in lieu of anymore information about what your *problem actually is*, you could just do `people = []` before the two `push`es and you'd get the result you wanted. But I suspect that isn't what you are going for.

Comment: This post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "update" method as is in JavaScript.

What you have  to do, is simply looping through your array first to check if the object is already inside.

```
function AddOrUpdatePeople(people, person){
    for(var i = 0; i< people.length; i++){
        if (people[i].email == person.email){
            people[i].name = person.name;
            people[i].age = person.age;
            return;                          //entry found, let's leave the function now
        }
    }
    people.push(person);                     //entry not found, lets append the person at the end of the array.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like this by generating an Array method. It takes two arguments. First one designates the object to push and the second is the unique property to check to replace if a previously inserted item exists.

```js
var people = [{name: 'peter', age: 27, email:'peter@abc.com'}];
Array.prototype.pushWithReplace = function(o,k){
 var fi = this.findIndex(f => f[k] === o[k]);
 fi != -1 ? this.splice(fi,1,o) : this.push(o);
 return this;
};
people.pushWithReplace({name: 'John', age: 13, email: 'john@abc.com'}, "email");
people.pushWithReplace({name: 'peter', age: 36, email: 'peter@abc.com'},"email");
console.log(people);
```