# Function to duplicate array of any number of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of integers, for example: `[1,2,3,4,5]`, I need to be able to take the array and output the array twice. The final result should look like: `[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`. This should be fairly simple, but getting stuck on comma separating the two arrays at the end.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var final = [];
for(i = 1; i <= array.length; i++){
 final.push(i);
}
console.log(final+final);
```

This could also be re-written in a function, so you can pass any number of values, such as function concat(12345){}

Comment: `array.concat(array)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/appending-to-array)

Comment: (first answer, second part, about `concat`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This could also be re-written in a function.

The people creating javascript thought so too, so they created [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for you!

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var out = array.concat(array);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Add Same Array a.

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(a,a)
```

Comment: Note: this will _modify_ the input. Question does not specify if that's acceptable or not but it's something that bears bringing up.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var new_array = array.concat(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way is to concat:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var final = array.concat(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do by using Concat function in javascript.

Read more about this .
[Array Concat Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)