# How to push items into an array using a loop?

Tags: javascript, web

I've been trying to output the array contents of `spliceJoin` in Chrome Developer Tools but it always output `undefined`

Am I missing something?

```js
var wordPermLength = 2;
var wordPerm = ['ab', 'ac', 'a'];
var spliceJoin = [];

function joinWords() {
  for (i = 0; i < wordPermLength; i++) {
    spliceJoin.push(wordPerm[i].concat(wordPerm[i++]));

  }
}
console.log(spliceJoin);
```

Comment: You're not running the function `joinWords()`, that's why. When you `console.log(spliceJoin)`, the function hasn't run yet to push them into the array - which rightly prints out `[]` at time of printing.

Comment: Also, you can just use `spliceJoin.join('')`

Comment: The code you provided actually outputs empty array `[]`. And yes, forgot to run `joinWords` function?

Comment: btw: why don't you just use `Array.prototype.join()`?
Your code becomes like: `var spliceJoin = wordPerm.slice(0, wordPermLength).join("")`

Comment: Apart from all the above, your function `joinWords` should take the `wordPerm` array as a _parameter_ and it should `return` the permuted array.   It should _not_ (as it is currently doing) refer to the variables with those names that are in the outer scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array 
This link will helps you a lot ... @castlenibill

Comment: *in Chrome Developer Tools...* When you assign value to variable, that statement does not returns anything and HENCE `undefined`. Please if thats the issue, try `JSFiddle` or `CodePen` or any other online tool

Comment: Please explain what you actually want this code to do, because most folks here have ignored the second `i++` that appears inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You missed to call function

```
joinWords();
```

You also used `i++` which were changing value of `i` giving wrong result
,Instead of `i++` you should use `i+1`

```js
var wordPermLength = 2;
var wordPerm = ['ab','ac','a'];
var spliceJoin = [];

function joinWords() {
    for (i = 0; i < wordPermLength; i++) {
        spliceJoin.push(wordPerm[i].concat(wordPerm[i+1]));
    }
}
joinWords();
console.log(spliceJoin);
```

Comment: If thats the only issue, you should comment it.

Comment: I just realised this is not the problem. When you create a variable and assign a value in **Chrome Dev Tools**, it prints `undefined`. I think OP is asking about this `undefined`

Comment: If you dont find this answer useful you can downvote it

Comment: I'm not sure about question myself, hence no votes. But my first comment was a suggestion

Comment: @Rajesh , I will consider your suggestion now onwards. Do not take it negative way.thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142158/discussion-between-dhiraj-and-rajesh).

Answer (score -1):

It does not return `undefined`, it's correctly returning `[]` (empty list). Until you call the `joinWords` function, the value of spliceJoin will not change, so it will be the empty list you've assigned with `var spliceJoin = [];`

Comment: actually his function doesn't return anything at all, so it is in fact implicitly returning `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `join` function in JS.

```
var wordPermLength = 2;
var wordPerm = ['ab','ac','a'];
var spliceJoin = joinWords();

function joinWords() 
{
    return wordPerm.join('');
}
console.log(spliceJoin);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend to simplify your code by using following one:

```js
var wordPermLength = 2;
var wordPerm = ['ab', 'ac', 'a'];
var spliceJoin = wordPerm.slice(0, wordPermLength).join("");
console.log(spliceJoin);
```