# Angular 5 - Push new element into array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function on a button click which I want it to add a new line to the current widgets data so that it will add a new one to the current.

Here is the code:

app.component.html

```
 <a (click)="addWidget()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right navbar-btn">Add Widget</a>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public widgets: any;

  constructor() {
    let count = 1;
    this.widgets = [
      { id: 1, title: 'Widget 1', config: { row: 1, col: 1, sizex: 1 }},
      { id: 2, title: 'Widget 2', config: { row: 1, col: 2, sizex: 1 } },
  ];
    this.widgets.map(() => {
      count++;
    });
  }

  addWidget() {
    console.log('This will add a new widget');
  }  

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try adding `this.widgets.push({ id: 3, title: 'Widget 3', config: { row: 1, col: 3, sizex: 1 }})` to `addWidget()`?

Comment: By the way, what the point of that `.map()` function? To get amount of entries inside of an array just use the `.length` property.

Comment: There is little advantage in using typescript if you define everything as `any`. Try creating a class or interface for widget and config.

Comment: Can you explain bit more what 'it will add a new one to the current' refers to? Do you want to modify rows of each widget to increase by one?

Comment: Yes, it would be good if the id was not repeated but mainly it's to add new data

Comment: So something like this might work?
this.widgets.forEach(widget => widget.config.row = widget.config.row+1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using an array `widgets` and can use the 
[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
method to add an element at the end of array. To maintain dynamic `id` and `name`
we can use the `length` property of Array's like below:

```
addWidget() {
    const title: string = 'Widget ' + this.widgets.length;
    this.widgets.push({ id: this.widgets.length + 1, title: title, config: { row: 1, col: 3, sizex: 1 } })
}
```

Comment: this.widgets.length+1 since he starts from Widget 1

Comment: What if... the first widget `[0]` gets removed and another one gets added, you end up with two widgets that have the same ID.

Comment: @Eric In that case the OP needs to keep a counter which is always incremented on push and never decremented. Then we case use that counter for id

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
  addWidget() {
this.widgets.push({ id: 3, title: 'Widget 3', config: { row: 1, col: this.widget.length, sizex: 1 }})
  }
```

Comment: Do NOT just copy and paste my code. To make it a valid answer you need to explain the code a bit.