# How to append a string on an array?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say I have an array field in a document:

```
entries: ["hello"]
```

I would like to append new elements to this array field i.e `["Yellow" ,"Blue"]`

I did some research and most the techniques replace the entire record. How can I achieve this?

I'm using javascript.

Comment: what language are you using? do you have more sample code? more context would be useful.

Comment: In the most languages you can do:
entries[] = "Blue";

Comment: edited, javascript.

Comment: what context do you need? i have an array field. how do i add elements to it without overwriting the whole field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this question: [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)
.

And looks like you are developing using firebase firestore, please take a look at their documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

You'll have to retrieve the document you want to edit first, append the array, then update it.