# How to take a list of id values and add them into a array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following problem:
I get a set of IDs from a json object:

```
getIDS which returns:

1299
1399
1499
1599
1699
```

Then I'd like to add them into an array like this:

```
[1299, 1399, 1499, 1599, 1699]
```

I've tried this:

```
let arr = new Array();
arr.concat(getIDS);
```

but it outputs it like this in the console:

```
[1299]
[1399] 
[1499] 
[1599] 
[1699]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: arr.push(getIDS);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: _“getIDS which returns”_ - returns _as what_? What is that supposed to be, which data type?

Comment: how does it look when you get response ? `console.log(response)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your callback is a string. Why not try split. like

```
getIDS.split(' ');
```