# Add/change values in Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, socket.io

I have an object named clients.

```
var clients = {"username" : test, "socket": asdasdkje3sf};
```

But I want to add some more clients. If I add an client on the following way:

```
clients = {
  "username" : username,
  "socket": socket.id
};
```

It gets overwritten every time I add a new value.
I have tried it on this way:

```
clients += {
  "username" : username,
  "socket": socket.id
};
```

If I do `console.log(clients)` it seems to work but it returns `[object][object][object][object]`.

How can I read the objects? And is this the best approach to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `clients` should be an array, not an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I read the objects? And is this the best approach to do this?

Use an array, instead of an object.

```
var clients = [{"username" : test, "socket": asdasdkje3sf}];
```

Instead of adding via `++`, use `push`

```
clients.push({
  "username" : username,
  "socket": socket.id
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a array data structure where you can push each object for `clients`. The way you are doing is incorrect as it concatenate the object with another object which result in invalid JSON object.

```js
var clients = [];
clients.push({
     "username" : 'username1',
     "socket": 'socket.id1'
});


clients.push({
  "username" : 'username2',
  "socket": 'socket.id2'
});

console.log(clients);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an array of objects (clients).

```
var clients = [{"username" : test, "socket": asdasdkje3sf}];
```

This way you can easily push new clients to it.

```
var newClient = {"username": "another name", "socket": "foobar"};
clients.push(newClient);
```

`push()` is an array [method provided by JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Answer (score 0):

To read or display and object use,

```
console.log(clients.username + "|" + clients.socket)
```

Add to above answers to add objects to an array, you can also use concat instead push if you are planning to merge more than two arrays. The difference is 'push' updates the same array, 'contact' merges and returns a new array