# How to use array push with filter and map method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a filter method that filters an item from an array using an `if` condition. Using the `filterArray` I then use map method.

I would like to add a second condition and push a new array called `OLD_ITEMS` to the `ITEMS` array. How would I go about doing this?

```
import { OLD_ITEMS, ITEMS } from './constants';

let filterArray = ITEMS.filter(item => {
    if (item.id === 'three') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

// TODO: add second condition here to push `OLD_TIMES` to `ITEMS`  

const options = Object.assign(
    ...filterArray.map(({ id, name }) => ({ [id]: name }))
);
```

Comment: You can do just `ITEMS.filter(item => item.id !== 'three')`

Comment: Would you like to use concat as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/351421/90997 ?

Comment: So you want to add all of old items to the `filteredArray` after you filter it?

Comment: What's the _second condition_ for adding the `OLD_TIMES` array? If the same filter predicate applies, you can just do `TIMES.concat(OLD_TIMES).filter(item => item.id !== 'three')`.

Comment: Could you update, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be a little more clear about what you mean by "push" OLD_ITEMS to Items. Do you want to concatenate/push ALL of the OLD_ITEMS to the end of if a single condition is met, or do you want to push subset of OLD_ITEMS that meet a certain condition?

I believe that this is what you're looking for, but it's hard to know exactly:

```
import { OLD_ITEMS, ITEMS } from './constants';

let filterArray = ITEMS.filter(item => {
    if (item.id === 'three') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

// TODO: add second condition here to push `OLD_TIMES` to `ITEMS`
const validOldItems = OLD_ITEMS.filter(item => {
    if (item === 'some_condition') {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

filterArray.push(validOldItems);

const options = Object.assign(
    ...filterArray.map(({ id, name }) => ({ [id]: name }))
);
```

Also, I highly recommend making your code more concise by returning the value of the conditional check, instead of an if/then

```
let filterArray = ITEMS.filter(item => {
    return (item.id === 'three');
});
```

Or even more concise

```
let filterArray = ITEMS.filter(item => (item.id === 'three'));
```

Grand finale of conciseness:

```
const filterArray = ITEMS.filter(item => (item.id === 'three'))
  .concat(OLD_ITEMS.filter(item => (item.id === 'some_condition'))
  .map(({ id, name }) => ({ [id]: name }))

const options = Object.assign(...filterArray);
```