# how to push from one array of class to another array in javascirpt?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of images with class="btn". When clicked, the listener replace the btn.src with an image randomly from images arr.

Then, I need to have the randomly-selected-item.src stored in an array for further operations. I was able to do the random insertion of image to btn class but dont know how to grab the randomly-selected item **each time** and push them in an array for further operation.

In short I am trying to check if the two selected items have the same src or not.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener('click', feedImages);
}


function feedImages(e) {
    var images = ["image/1.png",
                  "image/2.png",
                  "image/3.png",
                  "image/4.png",
                  "image/5.png",
                  "image/6.png"];

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
  document.getElementsByClassName("result").appendChild(img);

};
```

// how to grab this.img.src and push them in a new array each time so I will have something like

`var newArr["selectedImage.png", ....];`

after user clicked on any item

the HTML looks simple. Upon trigger SRC changes randomly to a new image.

```
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Comment: Read the MDN Docs carefully, there is everything you need.
[Array general Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) . The method you are looking for is called `push()` -> [Push new elements to array](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the easily by using the random number as a index of `images` array and using that to push in `newArr` as well as in `img.src`.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].addEventListener('click', feedImages);
 }

var newArr = [];
 function feedImages(e) {
    var images = ["image/1.png",
                  "image/2.png",
                  "image/3.png",
                  "image/4.png",
                  "image/5.png",
                  "image/6.png"];

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length);
    newArr.push(images[randomVal]);
    img.src = images[randomVal];
    document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].appendChild(img);
    console.log(newArr);
 };
```

```html
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<img class="btn" src="btn.png">
<div class='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm but can I now say if(newArr[0]==newArr[1]){then do this...}? how does arr element comparison work?

Comment: Yes you can do that