# Access array outside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to access array variable outside the loop. but its returning null. below is sample code.

```js
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
     result.push[i];
}
```

Comment: Use `()` on push. Like `result.push(i)`;

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `result.push[i]` does not do anything.

Comment: Why doesn't `push[i]` return an error BTW? I'm curious

Comment: @DarkBee because a function is an object in JS. `array.push[2] = 'foo'` creates a property `2` on the `push` method with value `foo`.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Thank you for that insight :)

Comment: actually want achieve below code `var args ={},fileObject = []; for (var i in files) { base64.encode('/opt/zipoutput/' + files[i], function (err, base64String) { convertval = base64String; var dataObj = { "actions": [ { "file_path": files[i] }] }; fileObject.push(dataObj); }); } console.log("fileObject111-----",fileObject);`

Comment: @Jaykumar - Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52852179/edit) your question to provide more updates/clarifications

Answer (score 3):

The syntex of push method is `push()` not `push[]`.

```js
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    result.push(i);
}
console.log(result);
```

For more info about `push()` look [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Comment: actually want achieve below code `var args ={},fileObject = [];
    for (var i in files) {
        base64.encode('/opt/zipoutput/' + files[i], function (err, base64String) {
            convertval = base64String;
            var dataObj = {
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "file_path": files[i]
                    }]
            };
            fileObject.push(dataObj);
        });
    }
    console.log("fileObject111-----",fileObject);`

Answer (score 1):

**push** is a method implemented on array. The basic syntax of invoking or calling a function is to specify parenthesis `()` after the function name.

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

```js
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
     result.push(i);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

```
var result = [];      
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {      
    result.push(i);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this also.

```
var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
         result[i]=i;
    }
```

If you want to use `push` then use like this `result.push(i)`