# Javascript arrays not merging

Tags: javascript, arrays

Javascript arrays are not merging:

```
var randomArr = [1,2,3];
var randomArr2 = [4,5,6];

console.log(randomArr + randomArr2); // "1,2,34,5,6"
```

I get the result : `1,2,34,5,6`
Why is that?

I expected [1,2,3] + [4,5,6] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: Or if you're looking to append, see [*how-to-append-something-to-an-array*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Comment: neither answer my question. randomShit.push(randomShit2) gives [1,2,3,[4,5,6]]

Comment: use `concat` to achive this.

Comment: @SQUIGGER please read the community Code of Conduct. Your language and attitude are not helping either side. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 1):

You want [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
var randomArr = [1, 2, 3];
var randomArr2 = [4, 5, 6];

const res = randomArr.concat(randomArr2);

console.log(res);
```

You could alternatively concatenate the arrays into an empty array - this solution is more modular and avoids nesting of `concat` calls.

```js
var randomArr = [1, 2, 3];
var randomArr2 = [4, 5, 6];
var randomArr3 = [7, 8, 9];

const res = [].concat(randomArr, randomArr2, randomArr3);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: finally that's what i was looking for

Comment: No problem @SQUIGGER, always glad to help.

Comment: how about `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrays)`?

Comment: That'd also work @SQUIGGER.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .concat
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

```js
let randomArr = [1,2,3];
let randomArr2 = [4,5,6];
let resultArray = randomArr.concat(randomArr2);
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't support adding or appending Arrays in the way you're trying to. It converts them to Strings: `"1,2,3"` and "4,5,6" then appends the second to the first, thus `"1,2,34,5,6"`.

You want to use `Array.concat` to merge the arrays:

```
var randomArr = [1,2,3];
var randomArr2 = [4,5,6];

console.log(randomArr.concat(randomArr2)); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for is:

```
var randomArr = [1,2,3];
var randomArr2 = [4,5,6];

var randomResult =randomArr.concat(randomArr2)
console.log(randomResult);
```