# Json Array to custom class array in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have following Json

```
[{"id":1,"role":"Admin"},{"id":2,"role":"Manager"},{"id":3,"role":"User"}]
```

I want to iterate this and add to my custom class array which has same properties (id,role,ischecked) in angular typescript.

My Custom class

```
class Roles{
    ID:number;
    Role:string;
    Checked:Boolean;
}
```

How can i achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by *custom class array*? Can you share the expected output

Comment: class Roles{
    ID:number;
    Role:string;
    Checked:Boolean;
}

Comment: add to array ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array

Comment: Also, as per your edit since the current array object doesn't have the `Checked` field - you either have to remove it OR make it optional like `Checked?:boolean`

Comment: i make Checked field optional but it does not work.
i want to convert this json data to my class array Roles[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the array :

```
  data = [
    { id: 1, role: "Admin" },
    { id: 2, role: "Manager" },
    { id: 3, role: "User" }
  ];
```

you can use the following syntax:

```
let roles: Roles[] = this.data;
```

Roles should be defined to:

```
export class Roles {
    id: number;
    role: string;
    checked?: Boolean;
}
```

1. The property names are case-sensitive
2. `checked` is optional now denoted by `?:`

---

EDIT

Since the API returns a response in the format of `Roles[]` you can simply do:

```
.subscribe((res: Roles[]) => { 
      let roles = res; 
   }
);
```

Comment: while assigning to result variable it give me following error
"Conversion of type 'string' to type 'Roles[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first."

Comment: I've made an edit. Can you try with that? Here's the working stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-del

Comment: now i am getting this error
"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Roles[]'."
Actually i am using api to get this data and convert that data into json by using JSON.stringify function.

Comment: Then you will need to share that code as well. Share the code of how you are subscribing to this API..

Comment: this.http.get('api/user/GetAllRoles').
    subscribe(res => {
      let roles: Roles[] = JSON.stringify(res); 
      console.log("api roles "+ roles)
    })

Comment: In what format are you getting the response intially from the API?

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: Do you understand how an API works? Is response of *type* json, string, xml...?

Comment: All I'm asking is when you hit the API from any client in what format does the API return the response? Is it of type json - If yes how does the response look?

Comment: return type is Task<object> and i am sending list of table with OK status.

Comment: Please share the response

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, role: "Admin", checked: false}
1: {id: 2, role: "Manager", checked: false}
2: {id: 3, role: "User", checked: false}

Comment: All you need to do then is: `.subscribe((res: Roles[]) => { let roles = res; })`. Now `roles` contains the entire json response as an array of Roles.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this json-response:

```
[{"id":1,"role":"Admin"},{"id":2,"role":"Manager"},{"id":3,"role":"User"}]
```

you should modified your request as:

```
this.http.get<Role[]>('api/user/GetAllRoles').subscribe((res: HttpResponse) => (roles = res));
```

This will cast the response to `Role[]` without the need of `JSON.stringify`. 
Before you have to declare `roles: Role[]`.