# Adding objects to array multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I have this array in the global scope:

```
const orders = [];
```

I want to push an object to this array.

```
const addItem = ($id, $name, $price) => {
  const $item = ({
    id: $id,
    name: $name,
    price: $price,
    amount: 1
   });
  orders.Push = $item;
  return orders;
 };
```

The thing is that I want to push an object into the array after every clickevent. For now it only adds 1 object to the array for the first clickevent, but after I click another time, it won't push anymore.

Comment: `Push` ?? is your custom function. I can't see any `array.push()` here .Where you are pushing it?

Comment: ``orders.Push = $item`` will not push anything. It will replace the contents of ``orders.Push`` with ``$item``. If ``orders.Push`` is supposed to be an array, try ``orders.Push.push( $item )``.

Comment: I think what you intended to do was `orders.push($item)` instead of `orders.Push = $item`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Comment: Hmmm... well if this code is actually pushing something into that array the first time as you state, then you must be using some framework that maps that orders.Push = $item to orders.push($item).  So if that is working then it must be how you are implementing it.  Can you post your code that actually calls the 'addItem' function?

Comment: This looks like a reducer, so you could actually call reduce and return the concatenation of `orders`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

orders.Push = $item may assing a value to Push like `[Push: $item]` and will replace the Push value on next call of function.

The correct way to use this can be as

```
const orders = [];
const addItem = ($id, $name, $price) => {
  const $item = {
    id: $id,
    name: $name,
    price: $price,
    amount: 1
   };
  orders.push($item);
  return orders;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unorthodox, but I managed to use your code, unmodified to obtain a reasonable result.

```js
// ▼ ============= No Changes ============= ▼
const orders = [];
const addItem = ($id, $name, $price) => {
  const $item = ({
    id: $id,
    name: $name,
    price: $price,
    amount: 1
  });
  orders.Push = $item;
  return orders;
};
// ▲ ============= No Changes ============= ▲

[
  { id : 1, name : 'foo', price : '1.00' },
  { id : 2, name : 'bar', price : '2.00' }
].map((data) => {
  addItem(data.id, data.name, data.price);
  orders.push(orders.Push); // Let's push "Push" onto the array...
});

console.log(orders); // Log the result...
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```