# Why do only some array methods create new instances?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript. Coming from a more object oriented background, one quirk I noticed is that some methods override an array, and some others make new instances. For example:

```
// initialize array
var arr = [
  "Hi",
  "Hello",
  "Bonjour"
];

// append new value to the original array
arr.push("Hola");

console.log(arr);
```

whereas `concat`

```
var arr = [
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "cherry"
];

arr = arr.concat([ // original array needs to be overridden
  "dragonfruit",
  "elderberry",
  "fig"
]);

console.log(arr);
```

Why is the behavior between the two methods not consistent?

Examples taken from: [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Comment: depends on the internal algorithm used is in-place or not.

Comment: Because some methods are meant to update current array and others are not. Functions like `concat`, `map`, `filter` are intended to return a new array with some permutation. `push`, `pop`, `unshift` `shift` are meant to mutate the same array

Comment: Just to make sure - are you asking why back in the 90's - the creators of Javascript thought it would be best to write it this way?

Comment: @Dekel I don't know what answer I am looking for -- is this just a historic quirk? Are "modern" methods leaning in a certain direction?

Comment: Have a look here to see which Array methods are mutable and which ones are not - https://doesitmutate.xyz, but basically the concepts here that you'd want to look into more to answer your question is `mutability` and `immutability`

Comment: @John-Henry certain use cases need certain capabilities,  for example you want something to change in your original array you will use any of method  which mutates original array ( less preferred though ) or other hand you don't wan to mutate your original array you'll use other methods

Comment: @John-Henry this has nothing to do with "historic quirks". Concepts of `mutability` and `immutability` exist in other languages as well, not just `JavaScript` - there's a reason why they exist so I'd suggest you look into those concepts more to answer your question.

Comment: @CodeManiac I see -- it doesn't seem like every method has a corresponding counterpart though, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks @goto1 I was asking that in regard to that other post, but I will certainly look into those concepts

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = 1, bar = 2;
```

Let's say you wanted to add the values `foo` and `1` onto `bar`. This is what you would do:

```
var foo = 1, bar = 2;
bar = bar + foo + 1;
console.log(bar) //4
```

But you did not do this:

```
var foo = 1, bar = 2;
bar + foo + 1; //ineffective
console.log(bar) //2
```

That is because the operator `+` simply just adds the values and returns the sum. So you still need to redefine bar. Whereas in:

```
var foo = 1, bar = 2,i;
for(i=0;i<foo;i++) bar++; //adds 1 foo times
bar++; //adds 1
```

You do not need to make a redefinition. This is because the increment operator assumes that you want to *increment* a value, not *find their sum*. So it does that.

---

*array*.concat(*foobar*) assumes that you want to get two arrays or values, join them together into a new, combined array, and then return the new array. In a sense, it is like the `+` operator. Thus it only finds their combination, not set the actual array, so you need a redefinition.

Whereas *array*.push(*foobar*) assumes that you want to add, stick, glue, or push a value to the end of the array, so it will do so. And because it itself has already added those onto the array, it doesn't need to be used in a redefinition.

They are used in that sense. It may be inconsistent, but you need to become used to it.

Answer (score 0):

concat() method does not change the existing array, but returns a new reference.