# Add array inside array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I push array into a new Array.
For example

```
var arr = ['one','two','three'];
var newArr = [];
```

Now I want `newArr[0] = ['one','two','three']`

I have tried using `push` function but it pushes all the elements of `arr` into `newArr`. I want to push the entire `arr` as it is in `newArr`

Comment: `newArr.push(arr)` does work like you intend it to: https://jsfiddle.net/msw3p17b/

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = ['one','two','three'];
var newArr = [];
newArr.push(arr); //<-- add entire original array as first key of new array
```

Comment: IDK why this is downvoted, I just upvoted it because it is the right answer. @jainilvachhani maybe your question isn't clear?

Comment: How you can add something to an array has been answered many times already. There is really no need to answer it again.

Comment: That does not, in itself, make my answer poor or worthy of downvoting. It's an issue inherant in SO's model that, when answering, one cannot always know whether the same question has been asked (far less answered) before - once, or many times.

Comment: [Should we downvote answers to obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202895/should-we-downvote-answers-to-obvious-duplicate-questions) Having yet another answer showing how to add something to an array is definitely not useful in my eyes. And given your rep, it should not be a surprise to you that this question already has plenty of duplicates.

Comment: @Dalibor Yes, you do.

Comment: @str Then it comes down to what high-rep users are expected to *suspect* are previously-asked/answered questions. Creating an array and wanting to put it in another array doesn't, to my mind, sound like an everyday thing (if the question was "how do I delete an item from an array" or "how do I return a response from an AJAX request", then, sure.). But, sure, I agree with your sentiment in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
newArr[0] = ['one','two','three'];
```

And this will work. Or use variable:

```
 newArr[0] = arr;
```

Also, array methods `push` or `unshift` will the same way in your situation work:

```
newArr.push(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered, so I guess your question is not really clear.

As you put your question, first and only element of newArray should be the arr array, then you use

```
newArr.push(arr);
```

as Mitya and Tiij7 said.

However, maybe you meant you want to join (concat) 2 arrays in a new array? Then you would use:

```
var arr3 = [].concat(arr, newArr);
```

or

```
var arr3 = [...arr, ...newArr];
```

Or you just wanted to clone the initial array? Then use

```
var newArr = [...arr];
```