# How to push array elements in the same order of existing elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have array `productData` with 69 elements and `productDatagreen` with 659 elements in `angular` application. When I do `push` all the 659 elements are going inside index 69 same thing happening `cancat`. Then I have total `length` of array 70.

I need `length` of array 69+659 and items should be in same row. How can I do that. This is my code.

```
this.productData.push(this.productDatagreen)
this.productData= this.productData.concat([this.productDatagreen])    
this.mapImageSeries.data=this.productData;
this.Chart.validateData();
```

Array screenshot

[image]

Comment: Try `this.productData.push(...this.productDatagreen)` or `this.productData = this.productData.concat(this.productDatagreen)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Comment: @Phil - Your first line of code worked for me with ... dots.

Comment: They should both work. Feel free to close this as a duplicate since both methods our outlined in the linked post

Comment: @Phil - You can write it as a answer. I have seen many threads. There is not easy to find. Need to scroll total page and make changes execute your project if not working repeat the same.

Comment: did u try this ?`this.productData =[...this.productData,...productDatagreen]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the @phil's comment.

```
this.productData.push(...this.productDatagreen)
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
this.productData =[...this.productData,...this.productDatagreen]
console.log(this.productData.length);//will console 728
```