# How to insert a new line in a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Array of Strings. Its a text with enumeration. So its like "1. abcde. 2. fghijk.
There is no new line. I want to write a loop that detects the place where the "2." is and the place before it (array[I-1]) there should be included a \n for the new line. But I don't know a command for place a new element in an array without deleting the existing element on the same place.
How can I do that ?

This is the code I got till now:

```
let el = document.getElementById('textinhalt').textContent;

for(let i = 0; i<el.length; i++){
if(el[i]=="2" && el[i+1]=="."){
 
 }
}
```

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: You call it an array in your post, but it looks like a string, which you're treating as an array of characters in your code. I think you'd find this much more convenient if you can just treat your data as an array of strings as `const data = ['abcde', 'fghijk', 'etc']`. It would be much easier to insert/delete/whatever into that structure than into a single string.

Comment: To push (add to the end) to an array, use [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), to add/modify "in between", use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351409/how-to-append-something-to-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loop. You can simply use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) or [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

both takes regex as needle, so you can check for another digits like `2.`, `3.`, `4.`, `5.` and so on with `/([2-9]\.)/` - this regex will find all signle digits with `.` after it, that is not 0 or 1

try this regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yjbs6x/1) and see how it works

```js
let el = document.getElementById('textinhalt').textContent;
document.getElementById('textinhalt').innerHTML = el.replace(/([2-9]\.)/, '<br>$1');
```

```html
<div id="textinhalt">1. abcde. 2. fghijk</div>
```

***UPDATE***

for bigger number I would suggest another regex
`/(?:[^1](\d+\.))/g` and you can test it again on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Vgqfi4/1)

demo:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('textinhalt').textContent;
document.getElementById('textinhalt').innerHTML = el.replaceAll(/(?:[^1](\d+\.))/g, '<br>$1');
```

```html
<div id="textinhalt">1. abcde. 2. fghijk 15. asdasd 10000. dsfsdfsdfsd</div>
```

Comment: I would even support larger numbers with `/([2-9]|([1-9][0-9]+)\.)/`

Comment: @jabaa I have updated my answer with regex that will support up to infinite numbers. It is a bit overcomplicated because of this first element but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to parse the text, insert the line before the index, and serialize it.

```js
const parse = (text) => text.split(/\s*\d+\.\s/).filter(l => l.length > 0);
const serialize = (arr) => arr.map((l, i) => `${i + 1}. ${l}`).join(' ');
const insertBefore = (arr, i, val) => arr.splice(i, 0, val);

const text = '1. abcde. 2. fghijk.';
const arr = parse(text);

insertBefore(arr, 1, 'Hello World.');

arr.push("I'm last!");

console.log(serialize(arr));
```