# If given two arrays with integer data how to move one element to other array and delete that element from where it was or vice versa

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 let a = [1,2,40,60]
let b = [50, 70, 80]
```

Suppose I want to move 40 from a to array b and delete it from a so I get

```
a = [1,2,60]
b=[50, 70, 80, 40]
```

Please help. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: @luk2302 This one complements your answer [How to append something to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/351409/9681386)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple `splice` to move the value:

```
b.push(a.splice(2, 1)[0])
```

This grabs the element you want from a, adds it to b, and removes it from a all at the same time.

**Edit:** As @malarres pointed out below, you can also concat the returned array:

```
b.concat(a.splice(2, 1))
```

Comment: a.splice is injecting an array inside the b array which we do not want

Comment: Odd. Splice only returns the element removed. What does the code look like?

Comment: Good idea @DanMullin, `b.concat(a.splice(2,1))` would also work

Comment: Thanks @malarres. I’ll have to remember that one 